# Is there any way to export an environment variable inside a cypress test

Tags: cypress

I have to create a new user in each test. To avoid duplicate emails, I always want to append the current date to the end of the mail. Since I then need this date in different places in the test, I would like to export it as env. Is there a way to do this directly from the test. The env must thereby also exist across multiple test files and only be reset when the test runs again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to provide the value as 2nd parameter

```js
Cypress.env('email', 'the-email')   // set
...
const email = Cypress.env('email')  // get
```

This persists across all tests in the run.

Comment: This is not true. Cypress.env() variables are only in scope for the current spec file in which they are set - https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env

Comment: You misunderstand - Jonas says "only be reset when the test runs again". The variable does actually persist for the whole run.